# Angular 13 Mock ngrx Store Subscribe in ngOninit

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

im working in angular 13 and im using ngRxstore. this is my code :

```
  userState:UserState | null = null;
  
  constructor(private store:Store<any>) {}

  ngOnInit() {


        // Subscribe to the user state and save info in the localstorage
        this.store.subscribe((state) => {
    
          this.userState = state.appUserState;
    
          if(this.userState && this.userState.user){
            localStorage.setItem('userState', btoa(JSON.stringify(this.userState.user.roles)) );
          }
          
        });
    
      }
```

can anyone guide me how i can unit test my store subscribe in ngOninit.
this is my test but it's not working:

```
        const testStore = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ['subscribe']);
        
        //....
        
         providers: [
            //..
            {
              provide: Store,
              useValue: testStore 
            }
          ]
    
    //...
      
        it(`#ngOninit test'`, () => {
      
    
    
        testStore.subscribe.and.returnValue(
          of({ user: userDtoMock, errorMessage:'',dataState:UserStateEnum.LOADED })
        );
    
        fixture.detectChanges();
    
        homeComponent.ngOnInit();
      
      });
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the general idea, adapt it to your needs :

```js
  // Mock properly
  const someState = {};
  const testStore = of(someState);
        
  //....
        
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Store,
      useValue: testStore 
    }
  ]
    
  //...
      
  it(`#ngOninit test'`, (done) => { // Add a callback function for async testing
    // Subscribe to your state
    testStore.subscribe(state => {
      // Check your test
      expect(...).toXXX(...);
      // Call the callback
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your example. it's runs but in my coverage in the line  if(this.userState && this.userState.user){  i have "if path not taken" "branch not covered" . do you have any idea why ?

Comment: `someState = { appUserState: { user: {} } }` should satisfy the condition